# Issue with Using Next.js 13 Server Components and Laravel Sanctum Authentication for User Data Retrieval

Tags: reactjs, laravel, fetch-api, next.js13, laravel-sanctum

I have a Laravel application that uses Sanctum for authentication. I'm currently working on a Single Page Application (SPA) with Next.js 13, utilizing the app router and server components. I have successfully retrieved user details when making requests from a client component using Axios, following the example from the [Breeze repository](https://github.com/laravel/breeze-next).

However, I'm struggling to retrieve authenticated user details from a server component in Next.js 13 using the fetch function. I've attempted to include cookies and set **{credentials: 'include'}** in the request headers, as shown in the code snippet below:

```
// api/user/route.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

const getHeadersWithAuth = () => {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Cookie', formatCookies())
    return headers;
};

const formatCookies = () => {
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const result =  cookieStore.getAll().map((cookie) => (
        !cookie.name.startsWith("_") ? `${cookie.name}=${cookie.value}` : null
    )).filter((cookie) => (cookie));
    return result.join("; ");
};

export async function GET(request: Request) {
    const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL + '/api/user', {credentials: 'include', headers: getHeadersWithAuth()});
    return NextResponse.json({'user':  await res. text() })
}
```

Despite my efforts, I haven't been able to make this work. I'm unsure of what I might be missing or whether this is even possible. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution to this issue? I'm trying to but with server component in next14 I only had 405 error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked everywhere and couldn't find the answer, but finally experiments brought me to this result. Basically you set laravel_session by yourself. I'm not sure if this is the right way, but it certainly works with server components.

```
async function getData() {
try {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/user", {
        headers: {
            Cookie: `laravel_session=${
                cookies().get("laravel_session")?.value
            }`,
        },
        credentials: "include",
    });

    return res.json();
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I used to retrieve user detail data from useAuth hook.

```
 const { user } = useAuth({ middleware: 'auth' })
```

Comment: Yeah, that works, but it uses Axios under the hood and can only be used in client components. I'm specifically trying to make the request with fetch in a server component.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).